# SpaCy: How do you check if two specific entities occur in a sentence?

Tags: python, spacy-3

I need to extract from a list of sentences (strings) all sentences that contain two specific entities and store them in a new list. The code I tried to use looks like this but unfortunately it doesnt work. I'm using Python and SpaCy.

```
sents_required = []

for s in sentences:
    if token.ent_type_=='SPECIES' in s and token.ent_type_=='KEYWORD' in s:            
        sents_required.append(s)
```

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me. Thanks for help!

```
sents_required = []

for s in sentences:
    token_types = [token.ent_type_ for token in s]
    if ('SPECIES' in token_types) and ('KEYWORD' in token_types):            
        sents_required.append(s)
```

Comment: You should also add some explanation to this answer, see how do I write a good answer [answer], which helps future readers too.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're declaring the condition is SQL-like, but that doesn't work in Python - you need to iterate over the list and access the data yourself. There are many ways to do this but here's one.

```
for s in sentences:
    etypes = [tok.ent_type_ for tok in s]
    if "SPECIES" in etypes and "KEYWORD" in etypes:
        sents_required.append(s)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work. The List is still empty.

Comment: The list could be empty if you have no sentences that contain both types of entities. Are you sure that you have a sentence that should be kept?

Comment: I made a few test sentences with both entities in it, but no results.

Comment: I solved the problem. your code was almost correct. only the brackets around `'SPECIES' in token_types` and `'KEYWORD' in token_types` were missing